# How to open chrome browser in Red Hat linux using terminal command?

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working on selenium testing and want to open my browser in a different region using terminal.
Please suggest.

Comment: What do you mean by *in a different **region***?

Comment: Means from a different country. So basically we have to open from terminal only. But how, that is my question.

Comment: Have you looked into locale environment variables?

Comment: A research on change region brought me to https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ . The command switch `--cros-region`  should to the trick. Unfortunately I could not guess what parameter it expects and cannot experiment (no chrome browser available). May be you could try with standard country names (eg `en-US`)...

Answer (score 0):

You can't open google chrome with  different region option.I think you must set region in your system setting.

you can start google chrome from terminal as below

run foreground

`google-chrome`

run background

`google-chrome &`

BTW, `url` is option